# How can I use python itertools.groupby() to group a list of strings by their first character?

Tags: python, string, python-itertools

I have a list of strings similar to this list:

```
tags = ('apples', 'apricots', 'oranges', 'pears', 'peaches')
```

How should I go about grouping this list by the first character in each string using itertools.groupby()? How should I supply the 'key' argument required by itertools.groupby()?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
groupby(sorted(tags), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

Answer (score 27):

You might want to create `dict` afterwards:

```
from itertools import groupby

d = {k: list(v) for k, v in groupby(sorted(tags), key=lambda x: x[0])}
```

Comment: ...But don't forget to sort it first!

Comment: @Matthew why do we need to sort?

Comment: @leleogere `itertools.groupby()` requires the iterable to be sorted, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: Thanks, I see why now. However, I don't understand the formulation: "***Generally**, the iterable needs to already be sorted on the same key function*". Why generally and not always then?

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> for i, j in itertools.groupby(tags, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    print(i, list(j))


a ['apples', 'apricots']
o ['oranges']
p ['pears', 'peaches']
```

Answer (score 2):

just another way,

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> t=defaultdict(list)
>>> for items in tags:
...     t[items[0]].append(items)
...
>>> t
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': ['apples', 'apricots'], 'p': ['pears', 'peaches'], 'o': ['oranges']})
```