# difference between dict(groupby) and groupby

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list like this

```
[u'201003', u'200403', u'200803', u'200503', u'201303',
 u'200903', u'200603', u'201203', u'200303', u'200703', u'201103']
```

lets call this list as 'years_list'

When I did groupby year,

```
group_by_yrs_list = groupby(years_list, key = lambda year_month: year_month[:-2]) 
for k,v in group_by_yrs_list:
  print k, list(v)
```

I got the desired output:

```
2010 [u'201003']
2004 [u'200403']
2008 [u'200803']
2005 [u'200503']
2013 [u'201303']
2009 [u'200903']
2006 [u'200603']
2012 [u'201203']
2003 [u'200303']
2007 [u'200703']
2011 [u'201103']
```

Then, I slightly changed my implementation like this,

```
  group_by_yrs_list = dict(groupby(years_list, key = lambda year_month: year_month[:-2]))
  for k,v in group_by_yrs_list.items():
    print k, list(v)
```

I have just added a dict, but the output is different,

```
2003 []
2006 []
2007 []
2004 []
2005 []
2008 []
2009 []
2011 [u'201103']
2010 []
2013 []
2012 []
```

I couldn't find out why. Please help me to find what the dict is doing actually.

(Python 2.7)

Comment: Remember that dictionaries don't have order. But as for why only one list isn't empty, that's odd

Comment: @Haidro: The answer by falstru should enlighten you.

Comment: @justhalf Oh of course!

Comment: @TerryA, comment is obsolete as of 3.7 - dict is ordered by insertion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) yields pairs of (key, **iterator**-of-group). If you are iterating the second pair, the iterator-of-group of the first pair is already consumed, so you get empty list.

Try following code:

```
group_by_yrs_list = {year:list(grp) for year, grp in groupby(years_list, key=lambda year_month: year_month[:-2])}
for k, v in group_by_yrs_list.items():
    print k, v
```

Comment: which means that all the grouped values refers a single iterator. Am I correct ?

Comment: @JohnPrawyn, Yes. [`itertools._grouper`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70850d6a16ee/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l197) objects share a single iterator. (`gbo->it`)

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is that `groupby` yields, in sequence, each key and a sub-iterator:

```
>>> for k, v in groupby(years_list, key = lambda year_month: year_month[:-2]):
...    print k, v
2010 <itertools._grouper object at 0x801c68950>
2004 <itertools._grouper object at 0x801bb3a90>
2008 <itertools._grouper object at 0x801c68950>
2005 <itertools._grouper object at 0x801bb3a90>
2013 <itertools._grouper object at 0x801c68950>
2009 <itertools._grouper object at 0x801bb3a90>
2006 <itertools._grouper object at 0x801c68950>
2012 <itertools._grouper object at 0x801bb3a90>
2003 <itertools._grouper object at 0x801c68950>
2007 <itertools._grouper object at 0x801bb3a90>
2011 <itertools._grouper object at 0x801c68950>
```

You need to turn each `<itertools._grouper object ...>` into an actual list before storing it away, because the *next* iteration of `groupby` resets the iterator.  If you don't, there's just the one useful iterator left, so when you print the contents of the dictionary, you get the one non-empty list (which uses up the iterator).  Printing it a second time, you'll get all-empty lists.

The key is to list-ify the iterators while they are still good (I see several others beat me to example code, I prefer [falsetru's variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19109326/1256452)).

Comment: From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby): Because the source is shared, when the `groupby()` object is advanced, the previous group is **no longer visible**. So, if that data is needed later, it should be stored as a list.

Comment: Yep, basically the same statement, but shorter and more precise (I don't say exactly *why* the older `<itertools._grouper object ...>`s become useless), but I suspect that version might fly over the OP's head :-)

Comment: Your answer is clear enough, just wanted to add some reference to docs.

Answer (score 2):

Try the non-streaming `groupby` operation from [`toolz`](http://toolz.readthedocs.org/)

```
$ pip install toolz
$ ipython

In [1]: from toolz import groupby

In [2]: years_list = [u'201003', u'200403', u'200803', u'200503', u'201303',
   ...:  u'200903', u'200603', u'201203', u'200303', u'200703', u'201103']

In [3]: get_year = lambda year_month: year_month[:-2]

In [4]: groupby(get_year, years_list)
Out[4]: 
{u'2003': [u'200303'],
 u'2004': [u'200403'],
 u'2005': [u'200503'],
 u'2006': [u'200603'],
 u'2007': [u'200703'],
 u'2008': [u'200803'],
 u'2009': [u'200903'],
 u'2010': [u'201003'],
 u'2011': [u'201103'],
 u'2012': [u'201203'],
 u'2013': [u'201303']}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2472176/895932), you can do this to convert it into a `dict`:

```
group_by_yrs_list = dict((k,list(v)) for k,v in groupby(years_list, key=lambda x: x[:4]))
```

It's because the output of `groupby` is an `itertools.groupby` object, which is a kind of generator, which apparently can't be used directly as the argument for the `dict` constructor.